# Are there different types of font-families in CSS?

Tags: css

I do not get how Calibri would be a font-family and fall under San-serif, which is also another font-family? Are both known as font-families in CSS or would they go by other terms. It seems weird to have a font-family to contain another font-family.

Comment: serif and sans-serif are font families that may contain many fonts. While Calibri is a font that is member of sans-serif font family.

Comment: If you just specify `font-family: sans-serif` then any available font installed in the system (that belongs to the sans-serif font family) will be used by browser.

Comment: That did not answer my question. So would Calibri also count as a font-family? @Mohammad Usman

Comment: No. Calibri is a font (not font-family). `font-family` is a CSS property that allows you to specify one or more fonts to display to contents of your web page. Only one of those fonts will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Sans-serif is both the name of a category of fonts, and also the name of a generic font family.

Calibri is a font family belonging to the Sans-serif *category*.

The definition of a font family is given is the [CSS Fonts Module Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-4/#font-family-prop), where it says

> A font family defines a set of faces that vary in weight, width or slope.

For a generic font family like sans-serif, the spec says that it:

> behaves as *an alias for* one or more locally-installed fonts belonging to the specified generic font category.

The `font-family` *property*

> specifies a prioritized [comma-separated] *list of* font family names or generic family names.

over which

> A user agent iterates through ... until it matches an available font that contains a glyph for the character to be rendered.